# Error messages on shutdown after upgrading to ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, error-handling, gnome-tweak-tool

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10.  Now I'm getting some error messages every time I shutdown my computer.  Anybody here can tell where to address these issues? The PC starts anyway but I'm not sure what to do about these messages which come so quickly that I can't even read them.

Comment: Do the following line by line in terminal: `sudo apt install pastebinit`, `sudo find /var/log/ -type f \( -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.1" -o -name "*.old" \) -delete`, `sudo find /var/log/ -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` and `sudo reboot`. This will first empty all logs so you only get the fresh lines from the current reboot. When you have start over open the terminal again and type `cat /var/log/syslog | pastebinit` and copy the link you get and add it to your question. (Hint: you can copy here with Ctrl+C and paste into your terminal window with Ctrl+Shift+V)

Comment: Same you can do for `dmesg | pastebinit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal, and run the following command:

```
dmesg
```

You should see the boot error messages.

Comment: Wow... I got pages and pages of lines!! Do you want me to post them all here?

Comment: Find the error, it should be marked with red text, red timestamp. The normal messages are marked with green timestamp.

Comment: Sorry I took so much time to answer this.  The messages kept changing and coming and going from day to day.  I get so many lines in red that I can't put them all in the comments!  I'll try to put a part of it that keeps repeating a lot.  I think it has to do with the Wifi..:
[ 1817.654460] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: regular scan timed out
[ 1817.654556] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[ 1817.654712] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1817.654720] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000200, count: 6

Comment: [ 1817.654720] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000200, count: 6
[ 1817.654726] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.541020.0
[ 1817.654734] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[ 1817.654740] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002A0 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1817.654745] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1817.654751] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D58 | branchlink2
[ 1817.654757] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004B016 | interruptlink1
[ 1817.654762] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004B016 | interruptlink2